# RarFile / [WinError 5]: Access Denied

Tags: python, windows, extract, zip, rar

I'm trying to write a script that will automatically extract the files from a rar or zip folder and put them somewhere, so as to make file organization faster. Included are the relevant sections of code:

```
import shutil
import os
import eyed3
import glob
import zipfile
import rarfile
import unrar
import patoolib

## create zipfile object of the downloaded album and get a tracklist

rarfile.UNRAR_TOOL=r'C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32'

downloads = glob.glob("C:\\Users\\John\\Downloads\\*")
music_zip = max(downloads, key=os.path.getctime)
if os.path.splitext(music_zip)[-1] == '.zip':
    music_folder = zipfile.ZipFile(music_zip)
elif os.path.splitext(music_zip)[-1] == '.rar':
    music_folder = rarfile.RarFile(music_zip)

print(music_zip)
print(music_folder)
temporary_album_folder = 'C:\\Users\\John\\Downloads\\temporary_album_folder'
if not os.path.exists(temporary_album_folder):
    os.makedirs(temporary_album_folder)

# patoolib.extract_archive(music_zip, outdir=temporary_album_folder)
# temp_list = os.listdir(temporary_album_folder)
# tag = eyeD3.load(temp_list[0])
# artist = tag.getArtist()
# album = tag.getAlbum()

# print(os.getcwd())

os.chdir(temporary_album_folder)
music_folder.extractall()
music_folder.close()
print(temporary_album_folder)
```

When I run this, I expect it to successfully extract the contents of the RAR into a temporary folder in \Downloads. Instead, the error message that I get when I try to run this in the console is:

```
C:\Users\John\Documents\PythonScripts>music_organizer.py
C:\Users\John\Downloads\d1ctus t3 n3c4r3(5).rar
<rarfile.RarFile object at 0x02C16350>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\John\Documents\PythonScripts\music_organizer.py", line 40, in <
module>
    music_folder.extractall()
  File "C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-package
s\rarfile.py", line 820, in extractall
    self._extract(fnlist, path, pwd)
  File "C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-package
s\rarfile.py", line 885, in _extract
    p = custom_popen(cmd)
  File "C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-package
s\rarfile.py", line 2813, in custom_popen
    creationflags=creationflags)
  File "C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.p
y", line 707, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.p
y", line 990, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied
```

I know a lot of other people have asked similar questions about WinError 5 and Python, so to address possible common suggestions in advance: I am running the terminal in admin mode, have turned off UAC, have unblocked the folder in question, and have opened full permissions to the folder and sub-folders in question. Does anyone know why this is happening and possible get arounds? Any help much appreciated.

Comment: It's not a security permission issue. `UNRAR_TOOL` should be the executable name (optionally the full path) of an unrar program. `subprocess.Popen` is failing because you're trying to execute the "Python36-32" directory.

Comment: I'm an idiot! Thanks much!

Comment: The Windows API has some rather useless error code mappings. Internally in the NT API the error in this case is `STATUS_FILE_IS_A_DIRECTORY` (0xC00000BA), which could not be more obvious, but it gets mapped to `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` (0x0005) by Windows, which misleads you into thinking it's a problem with file or object permissions.

Comment: @eryksun add all that info into an answer.

Answer (score 2):

### Refer to: Eryksun's comment

It's not a security permission issue. UNRAR_TOOL should be the executable name (optionally the full path) of an unrar program. subprocess.Popen is failing because you're trying to execute the "Python36-32" directory. – eryksun yesterday

The Windows API has some rather useless error code mappings. Internally in the NT API the error in this case is STATUS_FILE_IS_A_DIRECTORY (0xC00000BA), which could not be more obvious, but it gets mapped to ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED (0x0005) by Windows, which misleads you into thinking it's a problem with file or object permissions. – eryksun yesterday